# getting java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect on accessing twitter?

Tags: rest

I am trying to gather knowledge on REST services implementation.

By browsing blog, i understand that i can do this sample on twitter.

But is there any wadl files are there to get the resource path?

Also when i do normal search in browser http://www.search.twitter.com/search.json?q=soapui  it is returning response but when i do from Soap Ui I am getting java.net.SocketException: Permission denied:

Does it need any oauth keys? Please explain step by step how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to use oauth.

- You will have to register first at  https://dev.twitter.com/apps
- Create an application
- Then you will get your "Consumer key" and your
  "Consumer secret" etc.
- You should use these for authentication.

I have done this using python. I am not sure how to do with SOAPUI.

Comment: I created application "API Test".... Now i got consumer key and OAuth key etc...Now how to go for authentication part?

Comment: I am not sure how to do with SoapUI. You might check out this link. https://class.coursera.org/datasci-001/lecture/55 But it dosen't tell you on how to do with SoapUI

Comment: I have used the below code to run from soap ui.. but still getting the same error..